# Azure App Service API User Registration functionality

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-apps

I am currently experimenting with Azure App Service APIs. I am trying to create an application with register, register with OAuth account, forget password, reset password and login functionality.

Are there sample applications out there with this functionality?

Is the best approach to create a users table or to use the Azure Ad and Azure App Services API Authentication options?

Is there any similar ASP.NET Membership or ASP.NET Identity, where the user account database table is created for you and user account best practice is applied such as hashing of passwords.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of MS code samples on GitHub. Look into the Azure samples here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/

From there you can look for specific identity providers such as AD or AAD: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp

Typically these samples will contain a simple web app as well as the API in the same solution as a different project.

You should definitely use a pre-built identity service and if you are on MS stack I think AAD (Azure Active Directory) is the way to go.